# SSRS show X amount of rows per group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that in which I have some grouping, I want to limit the maximum amount of rows per group to be 5.

For example: In a group of purchased items I want to show the last five purchased per category.

I've tried with `Ceiling(RowNumber("GroupName")/5)` as when doing page break after `Nth` row but I'm not quite getting the results I want. I tried in the filter group property setting the `Top N` but this doesn't work at all.

Is there a way at all to force `RowNumber()` function to equal a fix value?

I'm finding this harder than I thought it should be. I cannot modify the dataset, so I can't do this by query.

Any workaround or idea will be much appreciated

Comment: Can you post the SQL? I'd do a ranking in the SQL and filter based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be able to filter a tablix using the `RowNumber` function, but you can hide a row if its row number is (for example) greater than 5.

Use the *Row Visibility" properties to specify an expression like this:

```
=(RowNumber(Nothing) > 5)
```

To restart counting for every group, use the grouping name as the scope (instead of `Nothing`).